# Use of latest dlls functions in an old XP with VS08 installed

Tags: c++, windows, dll, windows-7, windows-vista

I'd like to use functions from dlls that only Vista or later OS versions support. Because I am using XP and don't want to upgrade to Vista or Win7. Is there a way I can use the dlls/api functions to code in VS08 installed on my current XP ?

Comment: You'll want a VM for this. But really, you ought to be prepared to use the latest versions of the OS you target.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the Windows SDK you should be able to make binaries for later Windows versions. You wont be able to run things though.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3138

Answer (score 0):

In your code, use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` to check for the existence of a given DLL function. If a non-NULL pointer is returned, you can call the DLL function via that pointer until you call `FreeLibrary()`. If a NULL pointer is returned instead, the function is not available and your code can skip it and do something else.

If the function uses particular structures, enums, etc that are not defined in your VS environment yet, you can either install a newer SDK or define them manually directly in your code.